# MonoTouch support for accessing Mono.Security.Protocol.Ntlm.NtlmFlags

Tags: web-services, mono, xamarin.ios, ntlm, ntlmv2

We use NTLM auth to access an ASP.net web services from our MonoTouch app and everything works fine.

One of our customers uses the same app and the NTLM auth fails from our app but works from the iPad's Safari browser.

Looking at the packet flow from the customer, the server does not return `NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE`, when our app sends `NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE` message.

Looking the differences between our app's `NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE` message and iPad's Safari same message
Our MT app sets the NTLM flags to `0xb203` and Safari sets this to `0x88207`.
The `NegotiateNtlm2Key` is set to `0` in our app and `1` in Safari
Our app also sends the calling workstation domain and name fields whereas Safari send both as null.

The client's server is Windows Server 2003 and they also use Kerberos as their main authentication scheme and fall back on NTLM.

Would setting the `NegotiateNtlm2Key` flags in `Mono.Security.Protocol.Ntlm.NtlmFlags` help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NTLMv2 Session and NTLMv2 Authentication has now been implemented in Mono ([mono/master commit 45745e5](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/45745e5123267e8530b87b8dada9a89c6269b383)).

See [this article](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html) for a description of the different NTLM versions.

By default, Mono now uses NTLMv2 Session Authentication whenever the server supports it and falls back to LM & NTLM otherwise.

The default behavior can be configured by using the new `Mono.Security.Protocol.Ntlm.Type3Message.DefaultAuthLevel` property in `Mono.Security.dll` (see  [Type3Message.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/45745e5123267e8530b87b8dada9a89c6269b383/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Ntlm/Type3Message.cs#L103) and [NtlmAuthLevel.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/45745e5123267e8530b87b8dada9a89c6269b383/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Ntlm/NtlmAuthLevel.cs) in `mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Ntlm`).

This is similar to the [Lan Manager Authentication Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms814176.aspx) in Windows.

**Update 01/26/13**

There has been an issue with Microsoft Server 2008 RC2 not accepting the domain name that it sent back in the Type 2 Message's Target Name (or Domain Name from the Target Info block).

Therefore, we are now using the domain name from the `NetworkCredential` to allow the user to specify the desired domain.  This is also the domain name that's initially being sent to the server in the Type 1 Message.

Comment: Many thanks for adding this Martin. I tried out MonoTouch 6.0.8 which has this fix but it broke the authentication with my current Windows 2008 R2 server, which works in MT 6.0.6.   If you need it, I can email you a small MonoTouch program to repro this issue.

Comment: I emailed a test project to the Xamarin support center that repros this issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry that it took so long - had some annoying computer problems this week :-(  I finally have a fix for this, will commit shortly.

Comment: The problem was that your server accepts any random string as domain name in the `Type3Message` - except the one that it sends back in the `Type2Message`s Target Name (which is identical to the Domain Name field in the Target Info).  This is really weird.

Comment: I'll fix that by always using the domain name from the `NetworkCredential` - tested this with Windows Server 2012 (the standard version that you get in Amazon's EC2) and different Lan Manager Authentication settings and it's working fine there.  I also experimented with Samba's `ntlm_auth` tool - and this is always using the domain name from the local `smb.conf` no matter what I put into the Target Info block.  So I think letting the user specify the domain name in the `NetworkCredential` is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Hope to see the fix soon in MonoTouch.

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting flags ? Maybe but IMHO that's *quite* unlikely.

That code base was written in 2003 (and updated in 2004) and I'm pretty sure that I (as the author of the low-level code) did not have access to a Windows 2003 server or a Kerberos-enabled domain at that time.

The amount of required change, for a fallback, *might* not be too large (but I would not bet 5$ on that ;-) if you already have the environment to test it. I'm 100% positive that the Mono project would be happy to receive patches to enable this. You can also fill a bug report (priority enhancement) to ask for this feature at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

An alternative is to use the iOS API, which I assume Safari is using, to communicate with the ASP.NET web service and deserialize the data yourself. Hard to say which options is more complex.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. Will try to talk to customer to figure how to create a repro for this. I don't have Kerberos enabled domain setup. Will open a bug and add the data I have. Hopefully, someone else may have a test setup.