# RavenDB client onlinux connecting to windows server using mono http

Tags: mono, ravendb, gzipstream

I've just tried connecting to my RavenDB windows instance from linux using mono.   I'm getting a bizarre error with it, that seems to be mono related rather than raven related.

Here is my recreate code (works on windows):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Raven.Client.Document;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                var store = new DocumentStore()
                                {
                                    ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB",
                                    EnlistInDistributedTransactions = false

                                };
                store.Initialize();

                using (var session = store.OpenSession("system-events"))
                {
                    session.Store(new { Name = "Test" });
                    session.SaveChanges();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("done");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

and my mono version:

```
chris@x-ngx4:~/click/beta/Debug$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

and the error:

```
chris@x-ngx4:~/click/beta/Debug$ mono ConsoleApplication2.exe
System.IO.IOException: Internal error (no progress possible) Flush
  at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.CheckResult (Int32 result, System.String where) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Raven.Abstractions.Connection.HttpRequestHelper.WriteDataToRequest (System.Net.HttpWebRequest req, System.String data, Boolean disableCompression) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.Write (System.String data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectBatch (IEnumerable`1 commandDatas, System.String operationUrl) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient+<>c__DisplayClass68.<Batch>b__67 (System.String u) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.TryOperation[BatchResult[]] (System.Func`2 operation, System.String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, Raven.Abstractions.Data.BatchResult[]& result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Version of RavenDB please?

Comment: 2.0.2170-Unstable on client and server

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use a regular class instead of the anonymous class when defining the document?

Comment: For reference, here are links to raven's [HttpRequestHelper](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Abstractions/Connection/HttpRequestHelper.cs) and the mono implementation of [GZipStream](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.IO.Compression/GZipStream.cs) and [DeflateStream](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.IO.Compression/DeflateStream.cs).  Still can't find the root cause though.

Answer (score 6):

I think I found it.  [DeflateStream](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.IO.Compression/DeflateStream.cs) has extern references to zlib.  If you look at the [zlib header file](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/support/zlib.h), you will find some comments:

> deflate() returns Z_OK if some progress has been made (more input
>   processed or more output produced), Z_STREAM_END if all input has been
>   consumed and all output has been produced (only when flush is set to
>   Z_FINISH), Z_STREAM_ERROR if the stream state was inconsistent (for
>   example if next_in or next_out was Z_NULL), Z_BUF_ERROR if no progress
>   is possible (for example avail_in or avail_out was zero).  **Note that
>   Z_BUF_ERROR is not fatal, and deflate() can be called again with more
>   input and more output space to continue compressing.**

The message `Internal error (no progress possible)` is what `DeflateStream` returns when getting a `Z_BUF_ERROR` - but it doesn't continue, it treats it as a hard stop.  It should treat it as a warning and continue.  At least, that's my interpretation.

Can you raise this with the mono support team?  I'm not active in that group.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting.  Well, tbh. I'd call that API "broken" - IMHO status codes should not use name "ERROR" for something that's actually not a fatal error condition.

Well, this should be an easy fix, but I'm wondering whether `Flush()` or `CloseZStream()` could also return `Z_BUF_ERROR` for non-fatal conditions.

Comment: I've emailed them details.  Earlier I removed compression, suspecting an issue with the GZipStream, but this didn't resolve it.  Instead I got a "401" - which makes no sense, as I wasn't using authentication.  When I added auth details, I got the same response.  I'm going to investigate tomorrow in more detail.  However, fiddler wasn't co-operating, so will use wireshark to see what is going on.  I'll update here accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: It'd also be good to know which data `ReadZStream()` is being called with - maybe it's something that zlib doesn't like for some reason, like corrupted data or something like that.

Comment: @Chris - can you set `store.JsonRequestFactory.DisableRequestCompression = true` and run it while capturing the http with wireshark or similar?  The request body should then show the uncompressed value that is trying to go through gzip.

Comment: @MattJohnson Got it working through Fiddler - turns out mono isn't sending any auth headers... I think this issue might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392439/why-i-cant-make-httpwebrequest-working-with-ntlm-authentication

Comment: Mono 3.x has also received some NTLM fixes, I would try that version.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out?